# comparison of one column with another column of same row in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table Table1, with three columns Acc, Bal1, Bal2. I want to write a query to get all the Account (ACC) and Balance (Which ever is greater among BAL1 and BAL2).

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: `CASE WHEN` will be too much of coding, `GREATEST` does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample data and the output for the query

select * from acc;

```
   ACC       BAL1       BAL2
```

---

```
     1        100        200
     2        200        100
     3        123        444
     4        464        111
```

and the query to fetch required output

select acc, greatest(bal1,bal2) as "greater balance" from acc;

```
   ACC      greater balance
```

---

```
     1                 200
     2                 200
     3                 444
     4                 464
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `GREATEST` to get the greatest balance among the two columns for all the accounts.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 ACC, 100 BAL_1, 200 BAL_2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1 ACC, 300 BAL_1, 200 BAL_2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1 ACC, 50.7 BAL_1, 49.8 BAL_2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1 ACC, 0.5 BAL_1, 0.7 BAL_2 FROM DUAL)
  6  SELECT ACC, GREATEST(BAL_1, BAL_2) BAL FROM DATA
  7  /

       ACC        BAL
---------- ----------
         1        200
         1        300
         1       50.7
         1         .7
SQL>
```